# Set multiple value in multiple_select dropdown using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a multi_select dropdown with values say 1,2,3,4.

```
$('#changes-selectyes').trigger('change').val('1');
```

I want to select multiple value at once. But using current method i am able to set only one value. How can i select multiple ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass Array into thee val function:

Try this code

```
$('selector).trigger('change').val(['1','2','3','4']);
```

Answer (score 1):

## **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huseyinbabal/h919pguu/)**

You can use array notation as value like in the following code.

```
$('#changes-selectyes').trigger('change').val(['2', '3']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out i need to pass array inside the val() in order to pass multiple values.

`$('#changes-selectyes').trigger('change').val(['1','2','3','4']);`